# How to make one of the fragments full screen on landscape mode?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fullscreen, landscape, android-videoview

My question may seem to be a little confusing :

i'm developing an application in which i have a main activity and 4 fragments (4 pages)  , i need also to indicate that i use ViewPagerIndicator to have the swipe gesture .

fist of all : 
In one of my tabs (fragments) i need to play a video on full screen mode and i want force it to pass on landscape mode as well when i chose the appropriate tab ( i call it landscape tab ).

i did some digging and i found out that from the fragment , i can not do such thing ( force the window ,view , to become landscape ), or i did not found the right answer , though i used the code below but i get an error which is logic because i need to call there from the main activity as i understood it :

```
getActivity().requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getActivity().getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer solved my problem that is like yours:

```
public class YourClassName extends FragmentActivity {

static boolean isTablet = false;
static ActionBar actionBar = null;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
actionBar = getActionBar();

if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE) {     
    setContentView(R.layout.single_pane_fragment_layout);
    isTablet = true;
} else {
    setContentView(R.layout.viewpager_fragment_layout);
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13831134/104085