# How to convert Fragment/ViewPager Tabs to Full Screen

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabs

Basically what I am asking is identical to the functionality in the Twitter app, Plume, on the opening screen.  On a small screen (phone), there is three tabs you can swipe back and forth. I have this exact setup.  On a tablet it looks bad because there is too much white space.  In Plume, they simply loaded all three tabs on the screen -- no swiping, they all show up and take about 1/3rd of the screen each.  Better use of space.  How do you do this?

Here is my code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_layout);

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager());

    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);

    mViewPager
            .setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);

                }
            });

    for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                .setTabListener(this));
    }

    catName = getSharedPreferences("catName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    itemName = getSharedPreferences("itemName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);

}

public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

}

public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment f = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0: {
            f = new MasterFrag();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();

            f.setArguments(args);
            break;
        }
        case 1: {
            f = new FeaturedFrag();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();

            f.setArguments(args);
            break;
        }

        case 2: {
            f = new TopFrag();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();

            f.setArguments(args);
            break;
        }

        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("not this many fragments: "
                    + position);
        }

        return f;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return getString(R.string.mastercattab1).toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH);
        case 1:
            return getString(R.string.mastercattab2).toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH);
        case 2:
            return getString(R.string.mastercattab3).toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH);

        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Here is my XML Fragment layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >


            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:orientation="horizontal" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0" />

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Use different layouts for diff sizes http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html   ... For tablet layout shoud contain 3 placeholder/fragments for phone viewpager... Then in onCreate of Activity you should check which view exits pager or fragments and based on this setup activity properly for tabs or phones...

Comment: I have edited to add my own XML Layout. Also, the way I am doing it is this: A FragmentActivity with three inner ListFragments.  In each ListFragment there is an onActivityCreate where a different XML file is loaded.  I assume you are talking about the onCreate of the Main Fragment Actvity?  Is this method compatible?

Comment: Its all in "Creating Single-pane and Multi-pane Layouts" acapit... And if you use support library it should be compatible... You should only worry about ActionBar stuff (sorry, im on Android now and its hard to provide more accurate answer)

Comment: @Luksprog I shouldn't even be using the compatibility library now.  I am targeting Androind 4.0+ (in the early days I was going to make it backwards compatible).  It works though?

Comment: @Luksprog I am not getting any crashes though from that. Since I am not targeting old SDK versions, should I just dump the support library (and all references)?  Would that improve performance/stability?

Comment: @Luksprog I am only extending `FragmentActivity` which I believe is part of the Support class.  Most of the code for that Activity is up top. I  am only missing the menu code, and the three `ListFragments`.  Also, if anyone is up to a more detailed answer on the original question and mark down as answer I would love to mark them correct!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your most recent answer and a working xml layout plus this code below, I think it seems simple enough!  :)

Edit: So the idea is you have two XML layouts, one for small and medium screens (the xml in your first post) and another for tablets, large and xlarge (the xml in your working answer).

You could in theory switch between the two like this:

```
public class YourClassName extends FragmentActivity {

    static boolean isTablet = false;
    static ActionBar actionBar = null;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    actionBar = getActionBar();

    if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE) {     
        setContentView(R.layout.single_pane_fragment_layout);
        isTablet = true;
    } else {
        setContentView(R.layout.viewpager_fragment_layout);
    }
...
```

Then you could try calling this code below in onTabSelected in your fragment activity, but you may want to call it inside the fragment under onCreateView.  Note I made the variables static.

Example:

```
if (YourClassName.actionBar != null && YourClassName.actionBar.isShowing() && YourClassName.isTablet) {
    YourClassName.actionBar.removeAllTabs();
}
```

Also here is more info about ActionBar.hide() and .removeAllTabs():
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#hide%28%29

Comment: How do I do this programitcally? in the XML, I can define layouts, but not in the Java?

Comment: Thanks again!  I wont be able to try this until later this evening, but there is one thing I noticed about this solution. I don't want to hide the whole action bar, I still need it.  Just the tabs attached to it.  Maybe this is more of a ViewPager question? I don't know?  Maybe I need to disable that like the method you used?

Comment: Try using the .removeAllTabs() constant of ActionBar then, edited post above.

Comment: Hey got it! thanks.  I had to use a variation of your code, but it works great....

Answer (score 0):

I simply used this code from Google's site as an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:id="@+id/frags">
    <!-- "Fragment A" -->
  <fragment class="com.example.android.TitlesFragment"
            android:id="@+id/list_frag"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/titles_size"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    <!-- "Fragment B" -->
  <fragment class="com.example.android.DetailsFragment"
            android:id="@+id/details_frag"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Then I had to add the `ViewPager` above both Fragments.

Comment: Another alternative might be to just use full screen customdialogfragment.

Comment: I have yet to reward the 50 points for this.  If you list this as an answer with a sample, I'll can reward you for it since it looks like no one is going to get it yet.

Comment: The way I am doing it, I uses tabs/viewpager on a small screen.  I have successfully made better use of the space on a tablet screen with my method above.  However, on larger screens, I still have the useless tabs in the Action Bar that do nothing.  If that is also something you can point out, I'd be really happy!

Comment: Oh wait sorry took a deeper dive into this and CDF would not help here... let me think about this some more.

Comment: Try to call actionBar.hide(); to hide the bar.  ;)  and of course actionBar.show() to display it again;